# @babel/plugin-proposal-dynamic-import depends on a modules transform plugin

Tags: jestjs, babeljs

I'm trying to upgrade [@babel/preset-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/preset-env) from 7.4.5 to 7.5.0, and encountering this error:

[image: error]

This happens when running `jest` on a single test. My repo has `babel-jest` installed, and my project's `babel.config.js` is this:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

I'm new to configuring jest and babel on my own, but I'm confused about why changing `preset-env` from 7.4.5 to 7.5.0 would necessitate any changes on my part. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

remove node_modules and install again

`rm -rf node_modules`

https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10280

Answer (score -1):

This seems to have been fixed between when I posted this and now! I'm guessing an upstream dependency was patched.